# Open tabs one after another with Webbrower

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I am trying run a script to open multiple tabs

```
import webbrowser
import time

browser = webbrowser.get('"C:Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\Brave.exe" %s')

browser.open_new_tab("www.gmail.com")
browser.open_new_tab("google.com")

print("done")
```

It would only put one tab and then stop until I close the whole browser and then opens the browser again with the tab in second line.

What am I doing wrong?

It works fine when the browser is already open.

Comment: it works for me in chrome. I am able to open these 2 tabs in same browser window

Comment: Even when the browser wasn't open initially?